# How can I fix input width and label spacing to match surrounding lightning inputs

Tags: html, css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have a LWC, there is a section which comprises of filters. Most of them are standard lightning-inputs, but two of them, are custom lookup components. The problem is, I can't find a way to make them align and look the same.. even if internally it is applying slds css classes (to some extent). This is how it's looking right now:

[image]

As you can see, every lightning input is aligned correctly, but then the two lookup component's inputs are wider and with less space between the label and the input.

**This is the lookup html code:**

```
<template>
<label if:true={label} class={getLabelClass} for="combobox">
    <abbr if:true={required} title="required" class="slds-required">*</abbr>
    {label}
</label>
<div class={getContainerClass}>
    <div class={getDropdownClass} aria-expanded={hasResults} aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
        <!-- Search input start -->
        <div class={getComboboxClass} role="none">
            <!-- Text input -->


            <template if:false={useInput}>

                <slot 
                aria-autocomplete="list"
                aria-controls="listbox"
                role="textbox"
                id="combobox"
                onchange={handleInput}
                oninput={handleInput}
                onkeydown={handleKeyDown}
                onslotchange={handleSlotChange}
                ></slot>
            </template>
            <template if:true={useInput}>
                <input onfocus={handleFocus}
                       onblur={handleBlur} 
                       oninput={handleInput} 
                       class="slds-input" 
                       style="color: black;"/>
            </template>    
              
           
                <template if:true={isLookup}>
                    <!-- Search icon -->
                      
                    <lightning-icon
                    icon-name="utility:search"
                    size="x-small"
                    alternative-text="Search icon"
                    class={getSearchIconClass}
                    ></lightning-icon>
                    
                    <button
                    title="Remove selected option"
                    type="button"
                    onclick={handleClearSelection}
                    class={getClearSelectionButtonClass}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    >
                    <lightning-icon
                    icon-name="utility:close"
                    size="x-small"
                    alternative-text="Remove selected option"
                    class="slds-button__icon"
                    ></lightning-icon>
                    </button>
                </template>
            </div>
       
        <!-- Search input end -->
        
        <!-- Result list box start -->
        <div
        id="listbox"
        role="listbox"
        >
        <ul class={getListboxClass} role="presentation">
                <!-- Spinner to display when waiting for results of search -->
                <div if:true={loading}>
                    <lightning-spinner variant="brand" alternative-text="Loading" size="small"></lightning-spinner>
                </div>

                <template for:each={_searchResults} for:item="result">
                    <li data-id={result.id} onmousedown={handleResultClick} class="slds-listbox__item" key={result.id} role="presentation">
                        <div class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small" role="option">
                            <c-lookup-result template={_template} result={result}></c-lookup-result>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </template>
                <!-- Result list end -->

                <!-- No results start -->
                <template if:false={hasResults}>
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <span class="slds-media slds-listbox__option_entity" role="option">
                            <span if:false={loading} class="slds-media__body">No results.</span>
                            <span if:true={loading} class="slds-media__body">Loading...</span>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </template>
                <!-- No results end -->

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Result list box end -->
    </div>
</div>

</template>
```

In my case, "useInput" is true

**These are the getters:**

```
    get getContainerClass() {
    let css = 'slds-combobox_container'; // slds-has-inline-listbox  // sacado porque moleasta
    if (this._hasFocus && this.hasResults) {
        css += 'slds-has-input-focus ';
    }
    if (this.errors.length > 0) {
        css += 'has-custom-error';
    }
    return css;
}

get getDropdownClass() {
    let css = 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click ';
    if (this._hasFocus && (this._currentConfig || this.loading)) {
        css += 'slds-is-open';
    }
    return css;
}

get getComboboxClass() {
    let css = 'slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon ';
    return css += this.hasSelection() ? 'slds-input-has-icon_left-right' : 'slds-input-has-icon_right';
}

get getListboxClass() {
    return (
        'slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid ' +
        (this.scrollAfterNItems ? 'slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-' + this.scrollAfterNItems : '')
    );
}

get getClearSelectionButtonClass() {
    return (
        'slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_left ' +
        (this.hasSelection() ? '' : 'slds-hide')
    );
}

get getSearchIconClass() {
    let css = 'slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right ';
    if (!this.isMultiEntry) {
        css += this.hasSelection() ? 'slds-hide' : '';
    }
    return css;
}

get getLabelClass() {
    return this.variant === VARIANT_LABEL_HIDDEN
        ? 'slds-form-element__label slds-assistive-text'
        : 'slds-form-element__label';
}

get input() {
    return this._input;
}
```

**This is my code for what's on the image:**

```
    <template if:true={filters}>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
            <c-lwc-filter filter={filters.Nombre} input-variant="label-inline"></c-lwc-filter>
            <c-lwc-filter filter={filters.Codigo} input-variant="label-inline"></c-lwc-filter>
            <c-lwc-filter filter={filters.CodigoFabricante} input-variant="label-inline"></c-lwc-filter>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
            <c-lwc-filter filter={filters.CodigoBarra} input-variant="label-inline"></c-lwc-filter>
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal">
                <c-lookup label="Familia" is-lookup=true use-input=true configs={configsFamilia} onremoveselection={removeSelection} data-name="_familiaId"></c-lookup>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal">
                <c-lookup label="Marca" is-lookup=true use-input=true configs={configsMarca} onremoveselection={removeSelection} data-name="_marcaId"></c-lookup>
            </div>
            <c-lwc-filter filter={filters.Modelo} input-variant="label-inline"></c-lwc-filter>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

(the lwcFilter components are lightning-inputs internally)

I got the label to be inline, wrapping my custom lookup lwc inside a div with slds-form-element_horizontal class. But the problem is, as the "input" inside the lookup is not just a normal input, it is wider and as I said before, the spacing between the label and said input is very small.

How can I make them look the same as the base lightning-inputs? And for it to work on every screen size? (because I tried using margin or padding but it doesn't look the same with smaller / bigger screens)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include `slds-form-element__control` in `getContainerClass()`?
Something like this:

```js
get getContainerClass() {
    let css = 'slds-combobox_container slds-form-element__control'; // slds-has-inline-listbox  // sacado porque moleasta
    // ... rest of logic
    return css;
}
```

Does it break anything?